# How to check for the database if username is not found

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\jettp\Downloads\MockTest\MockTest\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Weight FROM MyWeight where Name ='" + txt_Name.Text + "'"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (txt_Name.Text != null)
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    MessageBox.Show("Username is found");

                    txt_Name.Text = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                    txt_Weight.Text = sdr["Weight"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_WarningMsg.Text = "Name not found";
                    con.Close();
                }
            } 
        } 
}
```

I tried using this command to search for the username which is in not found database, but database message kept saying that the name is found in the database. This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that `Username is found` because your `if` condition is always true.  Change your `if` condition to this :

```
if (sdr.HasRows)
{
    //your code
}
```